# Reading an XML file

Tags: iphone, xml

I created an iPhone application to read **[this](http://minihath.com/events/XMLfeeds.xml)** XML, but it does not work with this link while it is reading other XML files from other locations simply.

Can anybody test it for me to see if you can read it or not? If yes can you tell me how?

Comment: Sorry I'm having a little trouble understanding your problem. Are you saying you wrote an iphone application that reads from that URL, but it doesn't work when you try a different URL? What do you mean by "it is not working"? What happens?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.  What I gather is that you want to parse a different XML file while you're parsing the current one.  In that case, I would make another class that contains a different parser and then you can run them simultaneously.

Comment: my questuin is simple. i am writing a parser for xml it is work fine with all xml files. but when i tried to parse xml in the link it did not work. is there problem with xml in the link structure or there is special thing to parse that xml as it have arabic characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick test, worked just fine...

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *XMLEncodedString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://minihath.com/events/XMLfeeds.xml" ]];
    NSData *data = [XMLEncodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *xml = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [xml setDelegate:self];
    [xml setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xml parse];    
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError 
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [parseError localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *) string {
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"elementName %@ %@", elementName, currentElementValue);
    currentElementValue=nil;
    [currentElementValue release];
}
```

Comment: The code above works just fine. The questions has been answered. Accept the answer and ask another question.